# Combinations in Prestashop change stock to main stock via PHP

Tags: prestashop

I'm using prestashop for a shop.

I was wondering if anyone knew a quick php mod to stop the combination products having their own stock levels. The problem is that our supplier doesn't give us the stock levels for individual shell colours for rc cars we sell. The car is either in stock or out of stock. We use a csv import to manage our stock.

Obviously the combinations have separate stock levels. I really need the 'main' stock level to mirror across to the combination levels.

Is there a quick way of modifying the php to do this?

I was thinking of something like

```
$id_product_attribute['quantity'] == '$qty';
```

where `$qty` is the main qty. Another issue is that if you have combinations, it doesn't update the main stock when you use the csv update. I think its in the AdminProducts.php.

I am still using `1.4.7.0`.

I think its in the AdminProducts.php. *(I would post the php file here but it's too large.)*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place the code below in `<prestashop root>/overrides/classes/StockMvt.php`

The code will keep the quantity for all combinations at the same level. I.e. when you have 5 combinations and the stock for each combination is 10, then the stock for all 5 combinations will be reduced to 9, if one item is sold.

```
<?php
class StockMvt extends StockMvtCore {
    public function add($autodate = true, $nullValues = false, $update_quantity = true) {
            if (!$update_quantity)
                    return true;
            if ($this->id_product_attribute) {
                    $product = new Product((int) $this->id_product, false, Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
                    return (Db::getInstance()->Execute(
                            'UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute`
                            SET `quantity` = quantity+' . $this->quantity . ' WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int) $this->id_product) &&
                    $product->updateQuantityProductWithAttributeQuantity());
            }
            else
                    return Db::getInstance()->Execute('
    UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product`
    SET `quantity` = quantity+' . (int) $this->quantity . '
    WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int) $this->id_product);
    }
}
?>
```

I can't take credit for the code however. Eggbert74 came up with the solution in this thread: [http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/43828-combination-quantity/page_*st*_40](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/43828-combination-quantity/page__st__40)